# Connversion of scala.collection.Iterable<Row> to Java List

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert `scala.collection.Iterable<Row> to a java list` but its not allowing me giving me a compliation exception.
I have used

> scala.collection.JavaConversions.asJavaCollection

I get an error :

> The method asJavaCollection(Iterable) in the type JavaConversions
>   is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable)

Here the Row is

> org.apache.spark.sql.Row class

How can I resolve this? Any other way of doing it . I am new to scala to java conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code snippet below which maps to javaRDD call function and returns list of Objects. In your case you can override behavior of call function to reach your goal.

```
List<Object> resultList = dataFrame.javaRDD().map(new Function<Row, Object>() {
    public Object call(Row row) {return row.getString(0); }
}).collect();
```

OR

just using `import collection.JavaConverters._`

```
val input = "your Iterable Collection".asJava
val result = java.util.Arrays.asList(input)
```